# Visual Studio 2022 _ReturnAddress intrinsic not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I’ve been doing quite an extensive search, but I haven’t been able to find the solution to my problem.
I’m working on a Visual Studio 2022 solution generated from CMake (using a x64-windows vcpkg toolchain to retrieve depdencies) and when compiling my target library, I get 75 occurences of the following issue (of course not all the exact same, but they’re all saying `error C3861: '_ReturnAddress': identifier not found`):

```
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\ppltasks.h(2468,60): error C3861: '_ReturnAddress': identifier not found
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\ppltasks.h(2468,60): message : '_ReturnAddress': function declaration must be available as none of the arguments depend on a template parameter
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\ppltasks.h(2465,10): message : This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'bool Concurrency::task_completion_event<_ResultType>::set_exception(_E) const'
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\ppltasks.h(2659,2): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Concurrency::task_completion_event<_ResultType>' being compiled
```

From what I see it’s coming from calls of _CAPTURE_CALLSTACK(), which is defined as following in ppltasks.h:

```
#define _CAPTURE_CALLSTACK() ::Concurrency::details::_TaskCreationCallstack::_CaptureMultiFramesCallstack(_ReturnAddress(), PPL_TASK_SAVE_FRAME_COUNT)
```

_ReturnAddress is properly defined in intrin.h which is included in ppltasks.h.
I don’t make calls of _CAPTURE_CALLSTACK or _ReturnAddress in my own code.
So I’m not sure what’s wrong here it’s since it purely located in the system libraries.

Comment: Is there another stray `intrin.h` somewhere on your include path? Have you tried examining the preprocessor output?

Comment: I've checked for intrin.h using the "go to all" (ctrl+shit+t) menu, and only one intrin.h shows up. The preprocessor output is quite huge, this is a big project with lots of sub projects, so not sure that will be helpful unfortunately.

Comment: if you look in the preprocessor output you'll at least see which headers are being included and whether `_ReturnAddress` is defined

Comment: I've analyzed the preprocessor output and I see some mentions of _ReturnAddress 
here: 

`8>    __declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl _VCrtDbgReportW(
...
8>            void*          _ReturnAddress,
...
8>        );`

here:

`8>    __declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl _VCrtDbgReportA(
...
8>            void*       _ReturnAddress,
...
8>        );`

and here:

`8>void * _ReturnAddress(void);`

There is also one line showing the inclusion of: intrin.h

Not sure this is good news or not though.

Comment: Are these lines before the uses of `_ReturnAddress` though?

Comment: They appear above the uses of _ReturnAddress yes.